# cmake find_package slow due to finding the same package multiple times

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project built using CMake like this way:

- The top level project adds each sub module by calling `add_subdirectory`
- and each sub module add its own sub modules by calling `add_subdirectory`
- and in the end, the sub module calls `setup_src` function, where `find_package` is called to search different dependencies.
- Some of the dependencies are the same but used by different modules
- Question: I would like to avoid `find_package` for **the same** dependeny multiple times for different modules, how can I do that?

To give you a big picture, here is the cmake tracing visualization for investigating this issue.
[image]

**More Details**

I have a C++ project built with CMake, and this project has many sub modules, which has similar project structure, and I use CMake's `add_subdirectory` to add each sub module and their own sub modules recursively.

In each sub module, I have a CMake function `setup_src`, where I call `find_package` for searching for this sub module's dependencies. Some of the dependencies are shared by multiple sub modules, I find the overall CMake configuration process slow (17 seconds), and I did some profiling and found the `find_package` for the same shared dependencies multiple times, which makes the configuration slow. For example, modA depends on `find_package(gRPC)` and modB also depends on `find_package(gRPC)`, and I expected the second `find_package(gRPC)` either not happen or be very fast, but it turns out not the case.

I tried to avoid the second time `find_package` for the same dependency by using additional guard criteria in CMake since I assumed modA already found `gRPC` and modB doesn't have to find it again, but errors are reported by CMake saying something like `CMake Error at xxxx.cmake:578 (_add_library): Target "zzz" links to target "yyy::yyy" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?`, and I know `yyy` is a transitive dependency for the shared dependency (`gRPC` in the example), but it is not clear to me how I can avoid finding the same package multiple times while not running into this issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just put one `find_package` at the root of both modA and modB ? Not sure it would work, just a thought

Comment: @ClémentJean that is a good point. I avoid doing so because I would like to make each sub module can be built independently. Different developer usually only work on her own sub module and there is no need to build the entire project. But some developer and CI server does build the entire top level project.

Comment: maybe you could check the [`find_package` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#command:find_package). I read that `CMake creates a cache entry called <Package>_DIR to store the location found or allow the user to set it` (from [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Finding%20Packages.html#:~:text=%28see%20documentation%20of%20the%20find_package%20command%20for%20a,where%20to%20find%20everything%20provided%20by%20the%20installation.))

Comment: 2+ calls to `find_package` for the same target should be fast. You need to investigate why it isn't the case for you.

Comment: @ixSci in my case, `find_package` is called for different targets since each sub module has its own target. Does it mean it cannot be faster if called for different targets? I read `find_package` documentation, but I am not completely sure why it is slow.

Comment: I chose a wrong word. By "target" I didn't mean CMake target but rather a package your `find_package` is looking for. So if, for example, you are searching for boost multiple times bye invoking `find_package(Boost)` then CMake will execute a script to find it and set appropriate variables in its cache so the second time the script is entered it sees that the variables are set and shouldn't search for it again.

Comment: @ixSci thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in the question, I did find `find_package`  for the same package to be called multiple times, and in the CMake tracing diagram I posted above, the second call still takes similar time for some reason. The only additional parameter I add for `find_package` is the `REQUIRED`. Let me do more investigation to see if there is any clue. Thanks so much.